# A question about linked list

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, linked-lists

I would like to check the answer of this exercise:

*A circular doubled linked list with N elements has pointers that cost **k** bytes each of space in memory. How many bytes do the pointers of this list cost in total?*

Researching about circular linked lists, i can assume that each node has 2 pointers. So am i right to say that the answer is 2(n)k bytes?

Thanks.

Comment: It totally depends on your implementation. If you have a singly linked list as circular list then you have only n pointers.

Comment: It is double linked circular list

Comment: What is question actually asking. It is hard to understand. At first place it says that all pointers take k bytes and then it asks for the same thing

Comment: Its asking how many bytes does it cost

Comment: It means that a single pointer takes k bytes

Comment: I edited the question. It makes more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list takes $2*N*k$ bytes in total. A circular linked list is just a simple linked list with its last node's next pointer pointing back towards head. So, no extra pointer is required to make it circular. Hence, the total space is $2*N*k$.

Comment: Doesnt each node has its own previous/after pointers?

Comment: Each node has two pointers. So for N nodes, there are 2N pointers. Point is that we need not any extra space to make it circular. The memory required will always be same as a normal doubly linked list

Comment: Thanks for making it clear, so my answer is right 